# Can "on" be used as a preposition for "bargain"? (Please consider the examples below)

Tags: prepositions

1.) *"The bargaining **on/over** employees' benefits should end now."*

2.) *"We can never bargain **on/over** our human rights."*

Answer (score 2):

"Bargain over" and "bargain on" have different meanings

> bargain over
>   *negotiate*
>
> the employees were bargaining over better benefits with management
>   *the employees were negotiating better benefits*

whereas

> bargain on
>   *count on / thought that*
>
> I never bargained on her coming back after she left.
>   *I never counted on her coming back*
>   *I never thought she would come back*